# Modification indices in lavaan package when freeing some fixed parameters

Tags: r, r-lavaan, factor-analysis, structural-equation-model

I'm doing a confirmatory factor analysis using `lavaan` package in `R`. I want to see change in my model fit when I free some fixed parameters to find some *erroneously fixed parameters* in my model. There is an option in `summary()` that shows some *modification indices* but they are about when you *add* some constraints to your model. I want to see change in model fit after I *free* some already fixed parameters. Could I do that in `lavaan`, if not have you any other suggestions ? I think you really don't need the code to answer this question if you ever would, nevertheless here's the code I used:

```
model.mydata <-
'F1 =~ V3+V5+V15+V29+V31+V38+V40+V42+V44+V46+V48+V64+V65+V66
 F2 =~ V13+V17+V36+V37+V53+V56+V60+V62+V67+V68+V74+V75
 F3 =~ V4+V7+V11+V18+V25+V30+V32+V47+V52+V77+V79
 F4 =~ V10+V20+V26+V34+V41+V58+V59+V70+V72+V73+V76'

fit <- cfa (model.mydata, data=mydata)

summary (fit,fit.measure=TRUE,modindices = TRUE)
fitMeasures(fit)
```

Comment: Umm ... first, I think instead of "when you add some constraints to your model" you should have written "when you add some parameters to your model". If you think about, the meaning is completely opposite. Secondly, you have just four fixed parameters in the model above (not immediately obvious but the first factor loading for each latent variable is fixed to 1 by default). If you want to free them you'll need to fix the variance of latent variables. I'm not sure if you can compare  such models; I'd think not. But in any case, after accommodating the above, do you still have the same question?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually I haven't got used to these terms yet because I'm new to CFA (or SEM), but according to your terms, I think it's better to say I want to see the difference when I remove some observed variables from the model e.g. when I remove variables V3 and V5 (which are now related to F1) from the model. BTW I think I probably misunderstood the notion of _erroneously fixed parameters_ and I should edit my question some time later.

Comment: One more thing: you can only compare models based on the same data set i.e the same set of variables. So it's not that you remove a variable from the model (as in EFA). What you can do is fix its loading to zero -- this amounts to having one less parameter to estimate i.e a more restrictive model.